# Call netsh from Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, air, netsh

Hi I'm trying to set up a Wifi Hotspot from Adobe Air with

```
        var netsh:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo(); 
        var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("C:/Windows/System32/netsh.exe"); 
        netsh.executable = file; 
        var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>(); 
        processArgs.push("wlan set hostednetwork mode='allow' ssid='tests' key='tests123'"); 
        netsh.arguments = processArgs; 
        process = new NativeProcess(); 
        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData); 
        process.start(netsh);
```

The application is starting, but doesn't like the arguments - throwing the error:

```
The following command was not found: "wlan set hostednetwork mode='allow' ssid='tests' key='tests123'".
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Is it even possible!?

I have tried without quotes - this was just the latest attempt

Comment: note that typically the way you use and pass argument in a native process is: processArgs.push('wlan');processArgs.push('set');processArgs.push('hostednetwork'); etc....

Comment: Thanks I did try that but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
        var netsh:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo(); 
        var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"); 
        netsh.executable = file; 
        var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>(); 
        processArgs.push("/c netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=test key=test1234"); 
        netsh.arguments = processArgs; 
        process = new NativeProcess(); 
        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData); 
        process.start(netsh);
```